# ClearOS 6.3 add port forward rules breaks port forwarding, and deletes all rules

Tags: clearos

When adding a new port forward rule to existing rules, all the rules are wiped, my remote access is wiped, and when after that, trying to add a new rule, I get an error on creating the rule.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Error: Oooops!. Configuration is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Issue was a backup service that filled up the clearOS hard drive. I had 0% free space.

Sorted that out, and everything worked as expected.